# Issue of Maximum time execution in get_tweet.php using Phirehose.php twitter Stream Library

Tags: php, twitter-streaming-api

I am searching on Twitter Streaming api from last day but not exactly get to know how to use it. Finally I found 140dev streaming API framework. For this I followed every instruction from [140dev.com instructions](http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/twitter-database-server/install/). But when I run get_tweets.php file it display me an error

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in 
D:\xampp\htdocs\twitter-streaming\libraries\phirehose\Phirehose.php on line 741
```

I searched a lot on this and also increase max_execution_time from php.ini file but still the same problem.